# How to save scraped data through command in database

Tags: php, laravel

I have this in the command but not saving the database.

```
        $client = new Client(HttpClient::create(['timeout' => 60]));
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.bbc.com/news/');

        $model = new Scraper();
        $crawler->filter('.gs-c-promo-heading')->each(function ($node) {
            $model->title = $node->text();         
        });
        $crawler->filter('.gs-c-promo-summary')->each(function ($node) {
            $model->text = $node->text();
        });
        $crawler->filter('.gs-c-timestamp')->each(function ($node) {
            $model->time = $node->text();
        });
        $crawler->filter('.gs-c-section-link')->each(function ($node) {
            $model->country = $node->text();
        }); 
        $model->save();       
        $this->info('done success');
```

Giving this type of error

```
$ php artisan scraper:start

   ErrorException

  Creating default object from empty value

  at E:\wamp64\www\Laravel7Projects\system\system\app\Console\Commands\ScrapCommand.php:49
    45|         $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.bbc.com/news/');
    46|
    47|         $crawler->filter('.gs-c-promo-heading')->each(function ($node) {
    48|            
  > 49|             $model->title = $node->text();
   
    51|         });
    52|         $crawler->filter('.gs-c-promo-summary')->each(function ($node) {
    53|             

  1   E:\wamp64\www\Laravel7Projects\system\system\app\Console\Commands\ScrapCommand.php:49
      Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError("Creating default object from empty value", "E:\wamp64\www\Laravel
7Projects\system\system\app\Console\Commands\ScrapCommand.php", [Object(Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler), Object(stdClass)])

  2   E:\wamp64\www\Laravel7Projects\system\system\vendor\symfony\dom-crawler\Crawler.php:352
      App\Console\Commands\ScrapCommand::App\Console\Commands\{closure}(Object(Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler))
```

but with this mthod is working which is no need because I want to save all attributes in one new class

```
$crawler->filter('.gs-c-promo-heading')->each(function ($node) {
            $model = new Scraper();
            $model->title = $node->text(); 
            $model->save();        
        });
```

I want to save every attribute in the database but getting error

With this logic only saving first row where as i want to save all loop in the database

```
$client = new Client(HttpClient::create(['timeout' => 60]));
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.bbc.com/news/');

        $model = new Scraper();
        $crawler->filter('.gs-c-promo-heading')->each(function ($node) use ($model) {
            
            $model->title = $node->text(); 
                  
        });
$model->save();
```

Edit: Only titles are saving in the database whereas others not saving with this method because we are looping only titles in foreach
And map is not working whereas each in working you can check below code

```
$titles = $crawler->filter('.gs-c-promo-heading')->each(function($node) {
            return $node->text();
        });
        $texts = $crawler->filter('.gs-c-promo-summary')->each(function($node) {
            return $node->text();
        });
        $times = $crawler->filter('.gs-c-timestamp')->each(function($node) {
            return $node->text();
        });
        $countries = $crawler->filter('.gs-c-section-link')->each(function($node) {
            return $node->text();
        });

        $dataArray = [];
        foreach ($titles as $key => $item) {
            $newModelData = [
                'title' => $titles[$key],
                'text' => $texts[$key],
                'time' => $times[$key],
                'country' => $countries[$key]
            ];
            $dataArray[] = $newModelData;
        }
        Scraper::insert($dataArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `each()` you don't have access to `$model` variable (outside of the scope).
You should try `use()` to introduce `$model` variable inside of local scope of an anonymous function

```
    $crawler->filter('.gs-c-promo-heading')->each(function ($node) use($model) {
        $model->title = $node->text();
    });
```

Edit: If you want to save multiple items at the same time you could pluck necessary values and then create arrays of data according to your model attributes.

```
    $titles = $crawler->filter('.gs-c-promo-heading')->map(function($node) {
        return $node->text();
    });
    $texts = $crawler->filter('.gs-c-promo-heading')->map(function($node) {
        return $node->text();
    });
// same for times, countries
    $dataArray = [];
    foreach ($titles as $key => $item) {
        $newModelData = [
            'title' => $titles[$key],
            'text' => $texts[$key],
            'time' => $times[$key],
            'country' => $countries[$key]
        ];
        $dataArray[] = $newModelData;
    }
    Model::createMany($dataArray);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Osta for replying to me... i'm using this logic but saving only first row I want to save all loop

Comment: Only saving the first loop in the database of titles whereas others not saving because others have also loop
I have edit my question

Comment: Why is map() not working ? The point was to create arrays of titles, countries, etc. and every array should be same length. It doesn't matter then if you are going to loop over titles or something else, you are still accessing $texts, $times inside foreach

Comment: Yes Dear, every array has the same length but we are looping only the titles length that saving the database. I Want to loop every attribute which you send above and save like titles, times, country, texts but only saving titles because only putting foreach on this

Comment: map() giving this error because i'm using package Crawler  
`Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler::map()`

Comment: Dear you logic working fine but saving only `$titles` because it's only loop. come offset error on second `$texts[$key]`

Comment: Undefined offset: 18
`
$dataArray = [];
        foreach ($titles as $key => $item) {
            $newModelData = [
                'title' => $titles[$key],
                'text' => $texts[$key],  ==>offset
                'time' => $times[$key],
                'country' => $countries[$key]
            ];
            $dataArray[] = $newModelData;
        }
`

Comment: You need to create array of data which can be easily inserted in database. You should check outputs of $texts, $times, etc. and finally $dataArray.
If it doesn't have the structure we need then you should work on that. Maybe they are associative arrays, try turning them into normal indexed arrays after getting data. That could be reason for offset error ($titles['18'] doesn't exist)

Comment: Bhai Please can you edit your answer so that I could better understand it. Because I have many tries but not luck

Comment: Dear @osta You are right. I have not the same length of every loop. 
Then how can manage this? Please can you give me solution

Comment: It is hard to help you when I don't know all data, you will have to figure out how to connect promo-heading with promo-summary and other fields. 
Maybe for every heading node try to pull out other data (summaries,timestamps) connected to that heading.